# Avoid backslash expansion with echo in dash

Tags: shell, shell-script, echo, dash

First create a file with this exact content:

```
a\nb
```

I named this file `foo`, if I run the following, it prints the exact content of the file:

```
bash -c 'bar=$(cat foo);echo "$bar"'
```

But if you run it with `sh` instead of `bash` the result is:

```
a
b
```

The problem here is that the `\n` is being translated to a new line character that I do not want to.

My machine default `sh` is `dash`, the target machine is running an embedded linux with `ash` builtin `busybox`, so it is very minimalist, it works very similar to `dash` not `bash`.

If I run just `sh -c 'cat foo'` it get the expected result, but I want it inside the variable, how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the shell forks and executes the command. But each time a command (which is not a built-in) is executed, the shell forks. That's how shells work, and that's unavoidable.

Note: the shell doesn't translate anything. The `echo` command may. But you can use `printf` instead:

```
your_shell -c 'bar=$(cat foo); printf %s "$bar"'
```

Comment: I believe there are a misunderstanding here, my problem is not with the variable, the `sh -c` is just for simplify, the problem is that `dash` is translating the `\n` which I do not want to.

Comment: @TiagoPimenta I've updated my answer: it's `echo` that may do some translation. If you're not sure of the context (e.g. whether the string can contain special sequences), avoid `echo`.

Comment: well, it worked, but it is really strange for me, `dash` acts as `echo -e` ever!

Comment: @TiagoPimenta The problem is not `dash`, but `bash`, whose `echo` does not conform to [POSIX `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which does not allow any option (`-n` is a special argument).

Comment: That's how *most* shells work, which is, as I believe, a conseqeunce of their having to open a pipe for `$(` the subshell's output `)`. `ksh93` definitely does *not* fork in that case - which is, as I believe, a consequence of its using Korn's io lib rather than stdio.

Comment: @mikeserv According to `strace` output, `ksh93` *does* fork in this case. Note that otherwise it would have to detect whether the `cat` command is the standard one, which may be difficult, or alternatively regard `cat` as a built-in, but it doesn't.

Comment: Oh right - to get `cat` as a builtin you need to enable certain compile-time options and install all of the ast libs. Good point, @vinc17.